# Add Invitees to calendar event programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I've been trying to look for the answer to this quite some time.

Apple EventKit documentation isn't allowing changing meeting invitees programmatically since those properties in an EKEvent are read-only.

I'm trying to find a way to create a calendar meeting (not necessary using EventKit), adding invitees to the meeting and setting it programatically.

Any solution will be great,
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of meeting do you want to create? With whom? Are all meeting members on iCloud, or a CalDAV server, or Exchange? Please rephrase your question to be more specific on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I'm creating an EKEvent in order to add a meeting into the built in Calendar iOS app. However, I can't add E-mail addresses to the EKEvent participants property (It is a read-only EKParticipant object) so I'm thinking of other ways to to it..

Comment: I have this need also and I have failed to come up with a workaround. In order to try to get new API for this I filed a bug (feature request) a year ago. Apple closed it as a "duplicate". I encourage everyone to file their own request at bugreport.apple.com since their engineers say all the time that the number of requests sways them (not sure if that is true but it's all we got at).

Comment: Any progress with this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already figured out you cannot currently write meeting fields in iOS (AFAIK EventKit is the only API giving you access to the calendar database on iOS).

If you know what kind of account it is (and get the credentials from the user), you could sidetrack EventKit and directly create meetings on the server. Eg using EWS when the account is on Exchange or CalDAV when the account is on iCloud or Apple Calendar Server etc.

And finally you always have the option to send out meeting invites via [iMIP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6047). Though you would still need to get the event into the users calendar (so that replies have a target). Depends on your useless whether this is useful.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response! There is no way to send the invite without the credentials? I've seen some apps like Tempo AI that don't request credentials and manage to do so..

Comment: You can send out meeting invites via iMIP, aka eMail, which obviously doesn't require credentials. The question is what happens if the attendee replies. I don't know what Tempo AI is, but you could add sample data of invites they send. That might contain extra info on how it is done.